# Mongodb Explain for Aggregation framework

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Is there an explain function for the Aggregation framework in MongoDB? I can't see it in the documentation.

If not is there some other way to check, how a query performs within the aggregation framework?

I know with find you just do

```js
db.collection.find().explain()
```

But with the aggregation framework I get an error

```js
db.collection.aggregate(
    { $project : { "Tags._id" : 1 }},
    { $unwind : "$Tags" },
    { $match: {$or: [{"Tags._id":"tag1"},{"Tags._id":"tag2"}]}},
    { 
        $group: 
        { 
            _id : { id: "$_id"},
            "count": { $sum:1 } 
        }
    },
    { $sort: {"count":-1}}
).explain()
```

Answer (score 229, accepted):

Starting with MongoDB version 3.0, simply changing the order from

```
collection.aggregate(...).explain()
```

to

```
collection.explain().aggregate(...)
```

will give you the desired results (documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/)).

For older versions >= 2.6, you will need to use the [`explain` option for aggregation pipeline operations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#example-aggregate-method-explain-option)

#### `explain:true`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $project : { "Tags._id" : 1 }},
    { $unwind : "$Tags" },
    { $match: {$or: [{"Tags._id":"tag1"},{"Tags._id":"tag2"}]}},
    { $group: { 
        _id : "$_id",
        count: { $sum:1 } 
    }},
    {$sort: {"count":-1}}
  ],
  {
    explain:true
  }
)
```

An important consideration with the Aggregation Framework is that an index can only be used to fetch the initial data for a pipeline (e.g. usage of  `$match`, `$sort`, `$geonear` at the beginning of a pipeline) as well as subsequent  `$lookup` and `$graphLookup` stages. Once data has been fetched into the aggregation pipeline for processing (e.g. passing through stages like `$project`, `$unwind`, and `$group`) further manipulation will be in-memory (possibly using temporary files if the `allowDiskUse` option is set).

#### Optimizing pipelines

In general, you can optimize aggregation pipelines by:

- Starting a pipeline with a `$match` stage to restrict processing to relevant documents.
- Ensuring the initial `$match` / `$sort` stages are supported by an [efficient index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/optimize-query-performance-with-indexes-and-projections/).
- Filtering data early using `$match`, `$limit` , and `$skip` .
- Minimizing unnecessary stages and document manipulation (perhaps reconsidering your schema if complicated aggregation gymnastics are required).
- Taking advantage of newer aggregation operators if you have upgraded your MongoDB server. For example, MongoDB 3.4 added many [new aggregation stages and expressions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.4/#aggregation) including support for working with arrays, strings, and facets.

There are also a number of [Aggregation Pipeline Optimizations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/) that automatically happen depending on your MongoDB server version. For example, adjacent stages may be coalesced and/or reordered  to improve execution without affecting the output results.

#### Limitations

As at MongoDB 3.4, the Aggregation Framework `explain` option provides information on how a pipeline is processed but does not support the same level of detail as the `executionStats` mode for a `find()` query. If you are focused on optimizing initial query execution you will likely find it beneficial to review the equivalent `find().explain()` query with [`executionStats` or `allPlansExecution` verbosity](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/#verbosity-modes).

There are a few relevant feature requests to watch/upvote in the MongoDB issue tracker regarding more detailed execution stats to help optimize/profile aggregation pipelines:

- [SERVER-19758: Add "executionStats" and "allPlansExecution" explain modes to aggregation explain](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-19758)
- [SERVER-21784: Track execution stats for each aggregation pipeline stage and expose via explain](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-21784)
- [SERVER-22622: Improve $lookup explain to indicate query plan on the "from" collection](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-22622)

Comment: Thanks for the info will see if I can make any changes.

Comment: Shouldn't the `$sort` object be inside the pipeline array?

Comment: @JohnnyHK: Yes. Some kind folks are "correcting" the answer incorrectly :).

Comment: But this is not giving the "executionStats"

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar I've updated the answer with clarification on Aggregation Framework `explain` limitations as well as relevant feature requests for additional execution stats.

Comment: The limitation identified above has been addressed in 3.6 so you can now issue a query like, "db.price_per_minute.explain("executionStats").aggregate(["...

Answer (score 30):

Starting with version **2.6.x** mongodb allows users to do [explain with aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/release-notes/2.6/#explain-option-for-the-aggregation-pipeline).

All you need to do is to add explain : true

```
db.records.aggregate(
  [ ...your pipeline...],
  { explain: true }
)
```

Thanks to Rafa, I know that it was possible to do even in 2.4, but only through `runCommand()`. But now you can use aggregate as well.

Comment: Actually, you can explain aggregates with `db.collection.runCommand('aggregate', {pipeline: [PIPELINE], explain: true})` since MongoDB 2.2.

Comment: You're right, in 2.2 and 2.4 you can only explain aggregates through runCommand. Thanks for the upvote.

Comment: While the option technically exists via runCommand prior to 2.6, it is not guaranteed to produce correct results and should not be advocated. You should really only use this in 2.5.3 or newer (and expect there may still be some bugs lurking prior to the 2.6 production release).

Answer (score 23):

[image: The Aggregation framework]

The aggregation framework is a set of analytics tools within `MongoDB` that allows us to run various types of reports or analysis on documents in one or more collections. Based on the idea of a pipeline. We take input from a `MongoDB` collection and pass the documents from that collection through one or more stages, each of which performs a different operation on it's inputs. Each stage takes as input whatever the stage before it produced as output. And the inputs and outputs for all stages are a stream of documents. Each stage has a specific job that it does. It's expecting a specific form of document and produces a specific output, which is itself a stream of documents. At the end of the pipeline, we get access to the output.

[image: aggregation framework stage]

An individual stage is a data processing unit. Each stage takes as input a stream of documents one at a time, processes each document one at a time and produces the output stream of documents. Again, one at a time. Each stage provide a set of knobs or tunables that we can control to parameterize the stage to perform whatever task we're interested in doing. So a stage performs a generic task - a general purpose task of some kind and parameterize the stage for the particular set of documents that we're working with. And exactly what we would like that stage to do with those documents. These tunables typically take the form of operators that we can supply that will modify fields, perform arithmetic operations, reshape documents or do some sort of accumulation task as well as a veriety of other things. Often times, it the case that we'll want to include the same type of stage multiple times within a single pipeline.

[image: same type of stage multiple times within a single pipeline]

e.g. We may wish to perform an initial filter so that we don't have to pass the entire collection into our pipeline. But, then later on, following some additional processing, want to filter once again using a different set of criteria. So, to recap, pipeline works with a `MongoDB` collection. They're composed of stages, each of which does a different data processing task on it's input and produces documents as output to be passed to the next stage. And finally at the end of the pipeline output is produced that we can then do something within our application. In many cases, it's necessary to include the same type of stage, multiple times within an individual pipeline.

Comment: thank's, it was helpful to get a better understanding.