# How to check what index I use?

Tags: mongodb

Hi how can   check what index use , and number of scanned objects in aggregate query , something similar to 
*db.collection.find().explain()* ?

Comment: `explain` does show what index is being used.

Comment: `aggregate` does not yet have an explain: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4504

Comment: is there any other way , similar to explain , how to know what is best index for my aggregate query ?

Comment: Possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702080/mongodb-explain-for-aggregation-framework

Answer (score 1):

Right now, there is no explain functionality for `aggregate()` yet. However, in general indexes are only used for certain operators if they are the *first* element in the aggregation operator pipeline. For example, `$match` and `$geoNear`.

So in order to figure out which index is being used, simply run the `explain()` on a `find()` where the query matches your first `$match` options.

`explain()` functionality for `aggregate()` is an issue in JIRA: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4504 — I would suggest you vote for the issue on JIRA as well.

Comment: That doesn't mention running the explain() for the first find() at all.

Comment: I would have thought a comment and a link would have been enough, as this is 95% the same answer.

Comment: Is this still the case? Seems like the linked issue is closed?