# "InternalError No plan available on provide stats" on aggregate with explain

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

When I run my aggregation using explain, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702080/mongodb-explain-for-aggregation-framework) I get the following...

```js
{ 
  "stages":[
      {
         "$cursor":{
              ...
              "planError":"InternalError No plan available to provide stats"
      }
```

Any thoughts on what is going on here? I really need to be able to see what (if any) index is being used in my `$match` stage.

Comment: What is the whole statement from which you are seeing this produced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a MongoDB 2.6 bug. Check [the JIRA ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14636).

Answer (score 0):

I tweaked your query just a bit (adding a match to the front since I don't want to unwind the Tags array for all document):

```
db.collection.aggregate(
  [ 
    { $match: {$or: [{"Tags._id":"tag1"},{"Tags._id":"tag2"}]}}, 
    { $unwind : "$Tags" }, 
    { $match: {$or: [{"Tags._id":"tag1"},{"Tags._id":"tag2"}]}}, 
    { $group: { _id : "$_id", count: { $sum:1 } }}, 
    {$sort: {"count":-1}}
  ],
  { explain: true }
)
```

And got:

```
{
    "stages" : [
        {
            "$cursor" : {
                "query" : {
                    "$or" : [
                        {
                            "Tags._id" : "tag1"
                        },
                        {
                            "Tags._id" : "tag2"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "plan" : {
                    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor ",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "scanAndOrder" : false,
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "Tags._id" : [
                            [
                                "tag1",
                                "tag1"
                            ],
                            [
                                "tag2",
                                "tag2"
                            ]
                        ]
                    },
                    "allPlans" : [
                        {
                            "cursor" : "BtreeCursor ",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "scanAndOrder" : false,
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "Tags._id" : [
                                    [
                                        "tag1",
                                        "tag1"
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        "tag2",
                                        "tag2"
                                    ]
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$unwind" : "$Tags"
        },
        {
            "$match" : {
                "$or" : [
                    {
                        "Tags._id" : "tag1"
                    },
                    {
                        "Tags._id" : "tag2"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : "$_id",
                "count" : {
                    "$sum" : {
                        "$const" : 1
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$sort" : {
                "sortKey" : {
                    "count" : -1
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

While this doesn't quite address why your operation returns a planError, but maybe it can help some how.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue in my Rails app, fixed it by restarting rails server.
MongoDB version is 2.6.4.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this by rebuilding all indexes on the collection.  Not exactly elegant, but the error is gone now.