# MongoDB: $match and $explain

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, explain, nosql

I have the following query:

```
uno = db.prueba.aggregate(
    {$project: {a_gt_b: {$cmp: ['$num-a','$num-b']}}},
    {$match: {a_gt_b:{$gt:0}}},
    {$group:{"_id":"$a_gt_b",total:{"$sum":1}}},
    {$project: {"_id":0,"total":1}}
);
```

I want execute $explain command, according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25647252/2139691)  I have to take the $match portion but I don't know how.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That answer is super outdated (I will update it). Starting with Mongo 2.6 you can [explain your aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#return-information-on-aggregation-pipeline-operation) results:

```
db.orders.aggregate([
   # put your whole aggregation query
], {
   explain: true
})
```