# what does $ do with fields when aggregating in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

```
db.cata.aggregate([{"$unwind":"$review"},{$group:{_id:"review",cnt:{$sum:1}}}]).pretty()

db.cata.aggregate([{"$unwind":"$review"},{$group:{_id:"$review",cnt:{$sum:1}}}]).pretty()
```

what these two queries do in document..how $review and review do...how $ works with fields...

my document is

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("56dd01bdf3b660327b932da1"),
"product" : "super",
"price" : 10,
"review" : [
    {
        "user" : "fred",
        "comment" : "great",
        "rating" : 10
    },
    {
        "user" : "tom",
        "comment" : "i agree",
        "rating" : 3
    },
    {
        "user" : "vin",
        "comment" : "good",
        "rating" : 9
    },
    {
        "user" : "anubhav",
        "comment" : "too good",
        "rating" : 8
    }]
}
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! have you tried the [Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/literal/#exp._S_literal)? you might also want to have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702080/mongodb-explain-for-aggregation-framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [Mongodb doc](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) said

> The operand is a field path:
>
> `{ $unwind: <field path> }`
>
> To specify a field path, prefix the field name with a dollar sign `$` and enclose in quotes.

Answer (score 3):

$ fields in front of fields tell aggregation framework that inject actual value of field during execution.

e.g. in your case.

`db.cata.aggregate([{"$unwind":"$review"}` $review will be replaced by contents of review field which is

```
{
    "user" : "fred",
    "comment" : "great",
    "rating" : 10
}
...
```

But you really need to read documentation. It's much easier than writing questions here on Stack Overflow.