# MongoDB performance improvement for long aggregation pipelines

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to improve the performance of a mongo query(a page long) that uses various pipeline stages and transforms the data into various formats.

`SAMPLE DATA`

https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=d2075cafc09e4c1eb71d323b81fb474f

`QUERY`

https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=6ecf6baac4a247d6952096aa1cc019b3

`EXECUTION STATS WITH INDEX ON MULTIPLE FIELD`

https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=a1dd2e4286c14c3e886e120f59a993d5

The execution time of a single query is very less < 2 secs but on doing a load test with the following configuration

Total Number of records = 20,000
Concurrency - 50 (30 minutes)
M30 instance with 3 replica sets
The index was set on all match and sort fields
No other process/queries were running when the load test was done.

There is also a version of this query that uses `facet` with `group`. On running these query via a flask server the `db.profile` stats says the query execution took somewhere around 17-30 seconds.

Is this the expected behavior of mongodb when it comes to complex queries.

Comment: Unfortunately, as written, this question is off-topic: you haven't shown your query code or any example data; you're asking an opinion-soliciting question (question #1), you're asking why your code/query isn't working (#2), and another opinion question on best fit for your use case (#3). I suggest editing to contain a specific question (without the opinion asks). And also include any relevant query code + sample data. Otherwise, there's really no way to provide an objective answer.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I rephrased the question. Thank you for the comment. Also, the query and sample data are too long to add as a part of the question. Hence the links

Comment: @BhavaniRavi could you clarify why there is a project with all these fields ? IMHO all these $lookups  and $undwind have impact on performances for sure. Do you try to use Explain? Maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702080/mongodb-explain-for-aggregation-framework

Comment: @vokail it is a sample app created by our customers. They can create whatever fields they want. Also the lookup is to get real time data from another document. I removed the lookups and tried and the performance reduced to half which is 15secs still way beyond the expected.

Comment: @BhavaniRavi do you also tried explain query ?

Comment: @Vokail added the explain output. Not sure what to interpret out of it.

Comment: @BhavaniRavi when you read explain, you should search for stage winning plan and scan. In particular in your case I can see "IXSCAN" and this is good because your aggregation use indexes. My take here is try to use more indexes and see if this help or not